# How could I use rand in image_path helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my erb file, I want to write some fake image url data with using `rand`, because I have 12 different images with name from 1.gif to 12.gif, so I try to write:

```
 <img src="<%= image_path('gif2/#{rand(1..12)}.gif') %>">
```

but get the following result:

```
<img src="/images/gif2/#{rand(1..12)}.gif">
```

So how could I use rand in image_path helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this :

```
<%=image_tag image_path("gif2/#{rand(1..12)}.gif") %>
```

I modifed your code little bit, as you were doing some *redundant* things. But the BIG mess you were trying to do interpolation inside the `''`, which should be `""`.

Read this [`image_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) helper method for more details.

Comment: Yes, you are right, `<img src='<%= image_path("gif2/#{rand(1..12)}.gif") %>'>` is also worked. Thank you.